# How to play a pair against a maniac?

Tags: nlhe, online, no-limit, microstakes

I was playing against a maniac who was winning the pots by continuously reraising me (and another players) on flop and on the turn with nothing. Finally we had the following hand:

We were playing 0.01/0.02 shorted handed microstakes:

**Preflop:**

Villan1 (17 BB) limps

BTN Villan2 folds

SB Hero (25 BB) Bet 6BB A♠4♥

BB Maniac (130 BB) calls

Villan1 calls

**Flop (18BB):**
K♥ K♠ 4⋄

Hero (18BB) bets 13BB

Maniac calls

Villan1 folds

**Turn(45BB):** T⋄

Hero (4.5BB) goes all in

Maniac calls

Was it a hand played correctly?

**Spoiler:**

> on the river it appears 4♠ Maniac shows Q♠8⋄ and Hero wins 54BB.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're in the small blind?  For what reasons do you refer to the other player as "maniac"?  You say he's been reraising you--has he had to show any hands?

Comment: Why didn't you just go all-in on the flop?  Why hold back 4.5BBs?  Any the maniac - was he always going over the top or just a calling station?  From this hand he's just a calling station.

Answer (score 5):

Ok.  Let's take this one step at a time.

You describe your opponent as a "maniac".  However, that player displays no "maniac" behavior in this hand, so I'm not sure where to go with that.  I'd like more information on how you get that read on the player.  But we can still analyze the hand.

So you wake up with A4os in middle position and decide to raise 6x the blinds (pretty standard in low stakes).  However, managing odds and dealing with starting hands in low-stakes is just the same as in higher-stakes.  My first question is:  Why are you raising in middle position with A rag into a table with a "maniac" (or a really loose aggressive player)?  That is suspect to begin with.  As a general rule, when the table is loose - tighten up.  When the table is tight - loosen up a bit.  What you are doing here pre-flop is gambling IMHO.

Ok.  Flop comes.  You have two pre-flop callers.  From the action pre-flop I can only guess that Villain 1 started under the gun and checked the flop.  You then basically totally pot-commit yourself with the less than pot-sized bet.  What you are doing here is "betting on the fade" - meaning that you bet that you have "faded" the K on the flop with your KK44A hand (two pair with A kicker).  Clearly you are betting that your opponents don't have an K - or, perhaps simultaneously, trying to represent a K.  So you're trying to bet for value (two pair with A kicker) or you are firing a semi-bluff.  From an odds perspective, your chance of "fading" a K is about 90%.  Meaning that there is only a 10% chance the other two players have a K (2 Ks at about 2.5% per card for each player = 2.5% x 2 x 2 = 10%).

Those odds might justify a push post flop.  However, I wouldn't say you "played the hand" correctly necessarily.  It looks like you got frustrated with a bully, raised when you saw an A, got semi-lucky on the flop and you held up against a calling station.

What you need to do against a super loose and aggressive player - a maniac - is to wait for a strong hand (top ten or top 15 hand) in position and then push back.  Being in position - on the maniac's left - is key.  If you have AA, KK or QQ just push from any position.  If you go into the hand with the best of it, even if you went all-in pre-flop every time, you would eventually win.  In this case, you were out of position with a weak hand.  In short - you got lucky.  However, I'd rather be lucky than good.

Answer (score 0):

I trust this is a tournament if you are playing with 17 BB.

A4o is marginal here. I get are getting short stack and you move to the BB next so you kind of need to go with any Ace.

I don't like the big raise pre. That was 1/4 of your chips out of position. You did not need to build a pot as you have a maniac to get more action if you hit. If he raises you back you almost need to push.

You got bottom pair on the flop but it does not do much for you as he has a king or not.  If he has a K at least 4 is an out.

I get you want to represent a K but if you really had a K you would check to the maniac and let him bet. But if you check you give him a chance to bluff you off the pot. And you kind of need to call. If he has been bluffing this is a board he would bluff. Don't hold back 4.5. You are way past pot committed. I think you need to shove hope he does not have a K.

Maniac did not put you on a K and must have thought his Q was good. I think that was a bad call but he was deep and had a chance to take you out.